# Extending an attribute by adding a property

Tags: magento

I have a Magento site which will contain many attributes and attribute sets. Each category will have its own set and the customer wants the category and products view to show different attributes depending on which category it is in.

This would be easy enough to do in a switch / if statement but I don't want to hard code if possible.

My idea was to add a new property to the attributes called. 'display_on_frontend' which I could then use in a loop to see if an attribute should be displayed. Would this be possible to do?

There is a property already called Visible on Product View Page on Front-end which I initially wanted to use but when I get the attribute, it's not available in the data.

Here's the code that I am using to get the attributes on the product view

```
$_attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($_product->getAttributeSetId());

foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute) :
    $attributeFull = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                                                ->setCodeFilter($_attribute['code'])
                                                ->getFirstItem();
endforeach;
```

An example response of what is returned is

```
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [attribute_id] => 139
        [entity_type_id] => 4
        [attribute_code] => safe_working_load_range_tonnes
        [attribute_model] => 
        [backend_model] => 
        [backend_type] => int
        [backend_table] => 
        [frontend_model] => 
        [frontend_input] => select
        [frontend_label] => Safe Working Load (Tonnes)
        [frontend_class] => 
        [source_model] => eav/entity_attribute_source_table
        [is_required] => 0
        [is_user_defined] => 1
        [default_value] => 
        [is_unique] => 0
        [note] => 
    )
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to extend the attribute or on a reasonable way to address the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the back end, when you created the attribute, there's a yes/no select that's labelled "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end".

Go to Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > select your attribute "display_on_frontend" > Frontend Properties > Change "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" to "Yes".

Then to access the value of that attribute, you can simply call:

```
$_product->getData("display_on_frontend");
```

or just use the camel-case getter:

```
$_product->getDisplayOnFrontend();
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for replying. Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly, but I need to create a new property on the attribute rather than a new attribute itself. It's okay, due to lack of time I've gone a different, albeit hardcoded path but if anyone knows I would be interested in hearing if it's possible...